# How do i run su username -c "command " in a sequence

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, su

am trying to write a script that runs commands in a sequence as a user but su keeps doing every command at the same time instead of running them one after another

the script looks like

```
su username -c "cd /home/username/ ; git something.com"
su username -c "cd /home/username/ ; git something2.com"
su username -c "cd /home/username/ ; git something3.com"
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the `wait`command.

su username -c "cd /home/username/ ; git something.com"; **wait**

This will tell the script to wait for the sub-process to finish.

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
su username -c "cd /home/username/ ; git something.com; git something2.com; git something3.com"
```